# AJAX/jQuery and MySQL?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jsp

Can AJAX communicate with MySQL directly? For example, I just have a simple text box and with a trigger of a function it checks the database if the word is in there. If I wanted to use JSP, how will it be implemented? Can it be possible with jQuery? Or could I just create a JSON with all the words I have?

Thanks.

Comment: No, JavaScript cannot communicate directly with a MySQL DB.

Comment: Nope, you should load using AJAX a PHP script that connects to MySQL and echos the data you want. (or something like that :)) )

Comment: Hi Cristy, can I do it in JSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX runs clientside, and the code can be modified by any client that executes it. You should not have a direct connection to your database using AJAX, always put a server-side script in between to protect your database.

Even if it were technically possible, you **should not be doing this**.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX can communicate back to the web server. The web server can then communicate to the db. No direct connection between AJAX and the db. Exposing your db is probably a security risk anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, AJAX can't communicate with MySQL directly. You will always need a driver for MySQL. [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) can be accessed by HTTP, so with CouchDB it is possible! (CouchDB+Jquery=[jqCouch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqcouch))

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you can't connect to MySQL from JavaScript directly.

If you want a database that can do that then you can try [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). In fact, this is how [Futon](http://couchdb.apache.org/screenshots.html) works.